# How to make export to xml button using php in excel

Tags: php, laravel

I generate excel file using [this](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) extension. I am wondering now how to make export to xml button in this excel file, so people can easily generate xml file based on data in excel and save xml file locally?

Laravel version: 5.2
PHP Version: 7.1
Excel version: 2013

Comment: You want to make a button in your Excel file that exports the file to XML? Wouldn't that be the responsibility of the program viewing the file? I.e. Excel -> Save As -> XML.

Comment: I just saw that button in excel file and I interested is it possible to generate it.